# What is the better way to include files in cpp when multiple projects exist?

Tags: c++, makefile, include

I'm starting with my own projects by utilizing existing projects.

The directory looks like:

```
root/srcs/existing_project_1/Makefile
root/srcs/existing_project_1/*.hpp
root/srcs/existing_project_1/something_1/*.hpp
root/srcs/existing_project_1/something_2/*.hpp

root/srcs/my_project/Makefile
root/srcs/my_project/*.hpp

root/srcs/main.cpp
root/Makefile
```

`root/Makefile` compiles source files in each project by using:

```
make -C existing_project_1
make -C my_project
```

**Furthermore, when compiling `existing_project_1`, compiler commands in `root/srcs/existing_project_1/Makefile` uses include path:**

`-I.`

**As a result, when source files in `existing_project_1/something_1/*.hpp` include files in `existing_project_1/something_2/*.hpp`, the include directives can be:**

```
#include "something_2/*.hpp"
```

**The problem arrives when source files in `my_project` use source files in `existing_project_1`.**

One of files in `my_project` meets following include directives:

```
#include "something_2/*.hpp"
```

and the compiler fails to compile source files.

One of possible ways to prevent errors is to use following include path in the compile commands in `root/srcs/my_project/Makefile`:

`-I../existing_project_1`

,which seems to be weird (personally).

How to manage `Makefile` and compile source files in this case?

Should I use only one Makefile in `root_dir` instead of using `make -C`?

Comment: If multiple projects exist, then each should be used to make a proper library.  Then you install the library.  Then you include it with `<>` angle brackets.  Do not bother trying to use a library that isn't installed.

Comment: Just to point out, using recursive or non-recursive makefile structure has no relationship to what values you need to use with your `-I` compiler options.

Comment: You might consider CMake as your build system. It lets you have separate targets that expose their include directories and then targets list `target_link_libraries` to tell what other targets they depend on, then cmake automatically adds the appropriate `-I` flags.

Comment: @WilliamPursell in embedded development, much foreign code comes as source. Moreover, the need to support N different architectures makes "installing" a library a close to impossible task, so you are forced to build it dynamically.